# For Electron app that spawns node subprocesses, subprocess aren't getting Full Disk Access

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an Electron app.  It spawns a few node processes in the background, like so:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    pathToNode = pathToExtraResources + 'node';
    pathToBackgroundProcess = pathToExtraResources + 'script.js';
} else {
    const path = require('path');
    const parentPath = path.parse(path.resolve(__dirname, '../'));
    const appWorkingDirectory = parentPath.dir + '/' + parentPath.name;
    pathToBackgroundProcess = `${appWorkingDirectory}/extraResources/script.js`;
}


backgroundProcess = child_process.spawn(pathToNode, [pathToBackgroundProcess]);
```

So, in order to get all this to work, I've copied my node binary into the extraResources folder, along with the child process script.  I've also had to copy a bunch of node_modules into extraResources.

My subprocess, the node script, requires Full Disk Access permissions.  I've enabled Full Disk Access in "Security & Privacy" for both Terminal.app and my production build (re-enabling with each new build).

Thanks to [Debugtron](https://github.com/bytedance/debugtron/releases), I've determined that the subprocess are not, in fact, inheriting Full Disk Access....

Everything works *great* in development mode... it's the packaged app where I'm having trouble.

Comment: When electron packs your application it usually puts them into the resource folder (differences on mac vs windows)[https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#manual-distribution] you can make use of `app.getAppPath()` to get the path to your application dir (the one your build JS is run from)

Comment: This usually eliminates path issues on `build` vs `dev` issues when the filesystem is used.

Comment: Regarding the inheritance of permissions, are you sure that the node executables in your build project has the right permission? Maybe you can also start the processes via electrons build in node runtime via `nodeIntegration` flag on window creation.

Comment: Well, inheritance of permissions is the main focus.  Are you suggesting I do chmod 777 on the node binary before I build?  I could try that and report back.  And in fact, for dev mode, I run `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r @babel/register ./extraResources/script.js`.  Is there any way to do the same thing with Electron in production?

Comment: Also, I should mention, I just have a symlink to the binary on my system rather than the binary itself.  So I should definitely copy the binary over (rather than symlink) and restart this process, with chmod then package.

Comment: You should be able to run the scripts from within electron by requiring them from a electron browser window (full access to build in node when `nodeIntegration` is enabled) that windows can be hidden by setting `show: false`

Comment: Keep me updated, I'm on my way home right now and can't answer immediately

Comment: Okay, the chmod + binary thing failed, and so did inspecting package contents and dragging the node binary into Full Disk Access.  I'm going to try using the electron browser window method!

Comment: Update: since it requires 3 scripts, I had to make sure they all used commonjs syntax and also use 3 separate background windows.  The app is running with the new pattern, in dev mode!!! although it's noticeably slower than when it could use the background processes.  Haven't tried production yet - gonna grab lunch, brb

Comment: All right, in production, I get this error in Debugtron:  Not allowed to load local resource: `file:///Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/app/background_script.html`.  I have an idea for what to do - right now, the code is `backgroundWindow.loadURL(\`file://${__dirname}/background_script.html\`);` . I'm going to change it to use a dynamic variable (after making sure the file exists in the asar)

Comment: Nope, file doesn't exist in the ASAR, so I moved all the background scripts to extraResources/.   So now the code is: `backgroundWindow.loadURL(\`file://${__dirname}/../extraResources/background_script.html\`);`

Comment: Okay, I added a package.json, ran dependency-check on the extraResources scripts, added those to package.json, added electron and electron-builder, ran electron-builder install-app-deps... and voila!!!! It's now working in production!   I do see this error though in Debugtron: (node:80911) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information

Comment: Also, it's a lot slower, any way to get back the performance gains of using spawned subprocess?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, traffic was a horror. So first of yes the loading of native node modules that are not context aware are a issue, which one are you using? For the performance issue i'm setting up a similar scenario on my PC.